# How to set a image rotation on hover hyperlink

Tags: css, image, rotation

What i have is this:

```css
a:link {
    color: #A39B9E;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #7E7E7E;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
r {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #7E7E7E;
}
.rotatingimg{transition: transform 2s;}

.rotatingimg:hover{transform:rotate(360deg);}
```

```html
<table style="height: 20px; width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td style="width: 250px; text-align: left;"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com" class="rotatingimg" style="align:right;width:15px;height:15px;border:0"> <a title="Google" href="google.nl" target="_blank">Google.nl</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

But now only the image is rotating when I hover on the image. But I want that the image is rotating when I hover on the link name.

Does anyone know what I do wrong here and how I can solve this?

Comment: put the image inside the link

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: and apply the hover on the link

Comment: Can you please sent me a code snippert what you mean with that

Answer (score 0):

Include the image in the link.

```css
a:link {
  color: #A39B9E;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #7E7E7E;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

r {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #7E7E7E;
}

.rotatingimg img {
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.rotatingimg:hover img {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<table style="height: 20px; width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 250px; text-align: left;"> <a class="rotatingimg" title="Google" href="google.nl" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com" style="align:right;width:15px;height:15px;border:0">Google.nl</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution! Thankssss :)